# How to use a local docker image as resource in concourse-docker

Tags: concourse

I try to run a task in a docker image, which is not uploaded to docker hub, but instead installed locally (using `docker build -t tagname/tagname` .) So it exists on the (only) worker.

```
image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: tagname/tagname}
```

However, that approach fails with the following error:

[image]

Is there an easy way to have concourse run a docker image without having to push it to docker hub nor to set up a local repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the [rootfs_uri](https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html#task-rootfs-uri) task parameter.

You will have to find out where exactly in the worker filesystem the rootfs created by `docker build` is stored, and then reference it in the task with `rootfs_uri: file://<your_rootfs>`.

As the documentation says this is not recommended as you are not taking advantage of any of the concourse image caching logic.

Answer (score 1):

From @Josh Zarrabi's answer, which I accept for its correctness I learned, not to do it. So the correct approach is to set up your own docker registry, which is very simple using the https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/ container.

Comment: Hi, would you kindly look up my question? I tried to build my own registry too, but seemed I couldn't get it work with concourse 5.59
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860860/concourse-cant-connect-to-docker-repository