# Concourse Can't Connect to Docker Repository

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, concourse

I'm new to concourse and trying to set it up in my environment. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Virtualbox 6.1.4 r136177 on Windows machine. I managed to get the node running and concourse worker set up, and I was able to access my concourse dashboard successfully. The problem occurred when I was trying to run a simple hello world pipeline as outlined on this page : https://concourse-ci.org/hello-world-example.html

The error says :

```
[31mERRO [0m[0004] check failed: get remote image: Get https://index.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:55989->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
```

Googling for similar error indicates that virtualbox might not be able to connect to docker repository. So I proceed with installing docker to my system and run the following command :

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

But this this time docker successfully pulled the image. So I think it is not an issue with my virtualbox. Have anyone experienced the same issue and found a solution?

**UPDATES**

The following question inspire me to build my own registry :
[How to use a local docker image as resource in concourse-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499026/how-to-use-a-local-docker-image-as-resource-in-concourse-docker)

I have configured my local docker registry, and have verified that it does work by pulling my image from my own registry. So I configured a simple concourse pipeline to use my registry by modifying the hello world example :

```
---
jobs:
  - name: job
    public: true
    plan:
      - task: simple-task
        config:
          platform: linux
          image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source:
              repository: 127.0.0.1:5000/busybox
              tag: latest
              insecure_registries: [ "127.0.0.1:5000" ]
          run:
            path: echo
            args: ["Hello, world!"]
```

But then I run into the following error :

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
failed to ping registry: 2 error(s) occurred:

* ping https: Get https://127.0.0.1:5000/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers
* ping http: Get http://127.0.0.1:5000/v2: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers
```

Answer (score 0):

That `127.0.0.1` is likely referring to the IP of the check container, not the machine where Concourse is running as a worker (unless you have `houdini` as the container strategy). Try getting the actual IP of the machine running docker and try that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Your explanation is logical, and it might be the case. But I wonder where should I configure such settings? An example would be appreciated!

Comment: Which settings? To determine the worker IP or to use houdini?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case, concourse worker was installed on a qemu VM inside proxmox.

When starting a job with `fly-t tutorials trigger-job --job hello-world/hello-world-job --watch` command (given in [tutorial](https://concourse-ci.org/tutorial-hello-world.html#run-the-pipeline)), worker answered `ERRO[0030] checking origin busybox failed: initialize transport: Get "https://index.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:443: i/o timeout`.

It means that worker can't reach any DNS server.

There are two ways to solve this problem.

**First option**: run everything through [docker-compose](https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker). `docker-compose.yml` has setting for worker: `CONCOURSE_GARDEN_DNS_PROXY_ENABLE: "true"`. And all works fine. However, I tried to specify same setting when running worker directly inside VM (without docker), and this did not fix the problem.

**Second option (without docker)**:
Use this settings for your worker:

```
CONCOURSE_RUNTIME=containerd
CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_EXTERNAL_IP=192.168.1.106
CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_DNS_SERVER=192.168.1.1
CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_ALLOW_HOST_ACCESS=true
CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_DNS_PROXY_ENABLE=true
```

After setting these parameters my worker could see DNS server and can get access docker registry.

Replace `192.168.1.106` with your machine address in your local network. And
`192.168.1.1` with your DNS server.

These parameters are documented [here](https://concourse-ci.org/concourse-worker.html#containerd-runtime). Also you can get these description with `concourse worker --help` command.

```
Containerd Container Networking:
  --containerd-external-ip=                          IP address to use to reach container's mapped ports. Autodetected if not specified. [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_EXTERNAL_IP]
  --containerd-dns-server=                           DNS server IP address to use instead of automatically determined servers. Can be specified multiple times. [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_DNS_SERVER]
  --containerd-restricted-network=                   Network ranges to which traffic from containers will be restricted. Can be specified multiple times. [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_RESTRICTED_NETWORK]
  --containerd-network-pool=                         Network range to use for dynamically allocated container subnets. (default: 10.80.0.0/16) [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_NETWORK_POOL]
  --containerd-mtu=                                  MTU size for container network interfaces. Defaults to the MTU of the interface used for outbound access by the host. [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_MTU]
  --containerd-allow-host-access                     Allow containers to reach the host's network. This is turned off by default. [$CONCOURSE_CONTAINERD_ALLOW_HOST_ACCESS]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Cloned this repo - https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker

followed the directions as per the readme to generate the keys and then used the docker-compose.yml file from the clone to spin up the docker container.